# SQL: How to virtually combine two tables and link to the result?

Tags: sql, relational-database

Imagine three tables:

```
user:
- id
- name (string)

event:
- id
- description (string)
- points (int)

history:
- user_id
- event_id
```

---

Now imagine that the tables are currently filled with the following data:

```
user:
id: 1, name: foo
id: 2, name: bar
id: 3, name: beef

event:
id: 1, description: "walked 5 miles", points: +10
id: 2, description: "awake the whole night", points: +15
id: 3, description: "wasn't naughty", points: +20

history:
id: 1, user_id: 1, event_id: 1
id: 2, user_id: 1, event_id: 3
id: 3, user_id: 2, event_id: 1
```

So the schema is something like "how many points does a user have". Currently, e.g., the user 1 has in sum 10+20 = 30 points, right?

---

I would like to add another table with things the user can "buy" for his/her points.

```
gift:
- id
- points (int)
- description (string)
```

which is filled with e.g.

```
gift:
id: 1, points: -30, description: "a bottle of beer"
id: 2, points: -5, description: "coffee"
```

**My problem:**

Currently I am creating a new entry in **history** when the user gets points. But how would you substract points when he buys a gift?

I thought about something like a combined table which includes the events and the gifts entries:

```
[USER]-----[HISTORY]-----[COMBINED]--+--[EVENTS]
                                     |
                                     +--[GIFTS]
```

But I cannot really join them because I need the **gift** table somewhere else.

I have absolutely no clue how to do that in SQL, it's a long time since I learned it and I unfortunately never used it since then. I hope somebody can point me into the right direction :)

Thanks!

Comment: If you do the calculation in a view then it should do exactly what you want automatically.

Comment: You usually add a `balance` column in the `user` table, that is re-computed every time an event or purchase is performed.